# AngularJS: Data binding to array elements doesn't work with bulk update

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

The desired behavior is that I want to dynamically generate some navigation entries(some `<a>`s ) based on the data returned from backend. So I bind the herf and the text of each `<a>` to the fields of an element of an array `model`. Once the backend call returns, I assign the return data `data` to `model` to update the html. `model` and `data` share the same structure but this doesn't work for me.

The array looks like

```
     $scope.links = {
                    'cancelLink': 'http://cancelLink',
                    'Steps': [{
                      'label': "Step1",
                      'link': "http://1"
                    }, {
                      'label': "Step2",
                      'link': "http://2"
                    }, {
                      'label': "Step3",
                      'link': "http://3",
                      'active': true
                    }, {
                      'label': "Review",
                      'link': "http://review"
                    }]
                  };
```

The updating logic

```
$scope.loadLinks = function () {
                    $http({
                      method: 'GET',
                      url: '/links'
                    }).success(function(data) {
                        $scope.links = data;
                    });
                  };
```

HTML

```
<li><a class="text clickable" ng-href={{links.Steps[0].link}}>{{links.Steps[0].label}}</a></li>
<li><a class="text clickable" ng-href={{links.Steps[1].link}}>{{links.Steps[1].label}}</a></li>
...
```

The above code just failed silently without any output from the console. I tried assigning field-wise from `date` to `link` (`links.Steps[0].link == data.Steps[0].link`) and that works. So I wonder is this kind of bulk update not supported or something? Also I wonder how should I troubleshoot this kind of ng-directive issue down the road?

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into a Plnkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/c5AOjyuLhBGqqugT4VU4?p=preview .

One small stylistic change (though it doesn't break in either way), you should wrap the ng-href value in quotes:

```
ng-href={{links.Steps[0].link}}
```

should be

```
ng-href="{{links.Steps[0].link}}"
```

Otherwise, as you can see in the Plnkr, it works fine. I'm guessing your problem is that the $http call is not loading the JSON as you are expecting, $scope in your controller is not accessible to your HTML, or the $scope that is getting set in the load function is not the same scope that you're accessing.

If you post a more complete set of code, we can see where it's breaking down.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the binding ran, it bound the object *links* to your *template*.

So, if you make changes to the same object, it is reflected.
However, when you fetch the links with *loadLinks* function, you create a new object (with the same name). No changes have been made to the original object that was bound.

This is the normal expected behaviour.

One of the ways that I do is empty the links array and fill it with the new data from server.

easy way to do it is

```
links.length = 0 //empties the array
//now append to links the data from server
Array.prototype.push.apply(links,data);
```

Or you can use any sugar libraries to merge array that actually modifies the original array